# foreach get next item

Tags: c#, loops, foreach, ienumerable, enumerator

I have the following function but it's very long, dirty and I wanna optimize it:

```
        //some code
        if (use_option1 == true)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1)
            {
                //1. get subitems into a List<string>
                //
                //2. process the result using many lines of code
            }
        }
        else if (use_option2 = true)
        {
            //1. get a string from another List<string>
            //
            //2. process the result using many lines of code
        }
        else
        {
            //1. get a string from another List<string> (2)
            //
            //2. process the result using many lines of code
        }
```

this is working very good but it's very dirty
I wanna use something like this:

```
        //some code
        if (use_option1 == true)
        {
            List<string> result = get_item();//get subitems into a List<string>
        }
        else if (use_option2 = true)
        {
            //get a string from another List<string>
        }
        else
        {
            //get a string from another List<string> (2)
        }


            //process the result using many lines of code


        private void get_item()
        {
            //foreach bla bla
        }
```

**how shall I make the get_item function to get everytime the next item in the list?**

I read something about GetEnumerator but I have no clue if this is the solution to my problem or how to use it.

Comment: Is the processing code similar for each option?

Comment: In the first code segment, this "//2. process the result using many lines of code" comment, is this the same process?

Comment: yes, it's the same, but I cannot use it inside a function due the code from the start (//some code). so the only option is to use the foreach from a void

Comment: Tip: select a block of code in Visual Studio, click on "Refactor..Extract Method", and it will automatically move that code into a method, passing the appropriate arguments. In some cases it can't work - so you'll need to know a little more about what you're doing, which is always good.

Comment: refactor doesn't work ... gives me an error

Comment: ShaMora: As I said you need to understand your code better. It's better if you try to extract parts of your code into methods manually.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [yield keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) It is efficient and returns an IEnumerable. Consider the following example:

```
        List<string> list = new List<string> { "A112", "A222", "B3243" };

        foreach(string s in GetItems(list))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(s);
        }
```

Where you have a GetItems Method defined as follows:

```
public System.Collections.IEnumerable GetItems(List<string> lst)
{
    foreach (string s in lst)
    {
        //Some condition here to filter the list
        if (s.StartsWith("A"))
        {
            yield return s;
        }
    }
}
```

In your case you would have something like:

```
public System.Collections.IEnumerable GetItems()
{
    for (ListViewItem in ListView)
    {
        //Get string from ListViewItem and specify a filtering condition
        string str = //Get string from ListViewItem
        //Filter condition . e.g. if(str = x)
        yield return str;
    }
}
```

If you want to go further and use LINQ, then it will go down to one line:

```
public System.Collections.IEnumerable GetItems(List<string> lst)
{
    return lst.Where(T => T.StartsWith("A"));
}
```

Hope this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can read for this in the official documentation - with examples: [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator.aspx)

Comment: Is that just a link or did you mean "LINQ"?

Comment: I read already about IEnumerable.GetEnumerator Method but I'm a beginner in c# so I don't know how to implement it